# powershell if ($urlvalue -match $oldtext) - not working

Tags: powershell, match, contains

```
$LookFor = "nbc.local"
```

I have a variable `$urlValue` which returns `http://inside.nbc.local:7833/people/User Photos/Profile Pictures/nbcUS_MWallace_MThumb.jpg`

I am trying to find out where `$urlValue` contains `nbc.local` and following syntax does not work:

```
if($urlValue -match $LookFor)
{
   write-host $urlValue
}
```

I tried `if($urlValue -match [regex]::Escape($LookFor))` and it does not work. I also tried
`if($urlValue -match "nbc.local")`

Am I missing something?

Comment: What does $urlValue.gettype() return?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
$LookFor = "nbc.local"
$urlValue = 'http://inside.nbc.local:7833/people/User Photos/Profile Pictures/nbcUS_MWallace_MThumb.jpg'
$urlValue -match $LookFor

True
```

Comment: I can't look for the entire url. I need to see whether nbc.local exists in the url or not because the last part of the url nbcUS_MWallace_MThumb.jpg changes

Comment: Doesn't matter.  If you take that code snippet and replace the last part with something else, or even remove it completely it will still match.

Answer (score 0):

Is $urlValue a string, or did you try using `$urlValue.ToString()`?
If $urlValue is some sort of object it may have issues getting a `-match` from it.

```
$urlValue|?{$_.ToString() -match "nbc.local"}
```

Comment: ToString() kinda helps but match still does not work. It list all the all the url when i do write-host $urlValue. It should only list the url that has nbc.local in it.

Comment: I think we need to know more exactly what is in $urlValue, and what kind of object it is.